# Monitoring Web Analytics Implementation

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I would like to monitor the analytics implemented on about 20 sites over which I have no direct control.  There are software solutions as well as online services which monitor websites for changes but these usually focus on images, links and text which is obviously not what I need to track. Is there an of the shelf solutions that would allow to track changes to JavaScript and meta tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WASP](http://webanalyticssolutionprofiler.com/)... its one of the tools we use for QA.

Answer (score 0):

I have found WASP is the best tool that you run yourself to audit tag implementation.
SaaS services include:-

Observpoint:
http://www.observepoint.com/

For Omniture, Omniture's Digital Pulse
http://www.omniture.com/en/products/analytics/digitalpulse